How to gstreamer record to file from a live video method tcpclientsrc application/x-rtp-stream encoding JPEG video stream?
I have this working at live camera video stream using Gstreamer sent with tcpserversink, jpegenc, rtpjpegpay, and rtpstreampay.
I have this working at open broadcast studio receives using Gstreamer: tcpclientsrc host=ipaddress port=port ! application/x-rtp-stream,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=JPEG  ! rtpstreamdepay ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! decodebin ! queue ! video.
How can I use command line gstreamer to get it from live camera source (similar as OBS above) and record to file as matroska mkv and/or mpeg mp4, or may consider motion mjpeg?
Gstreamer Command Line:
gst-launch-1.0 -e tcpclientsrc host=ipaddress port=port ! application/x-rtp-stream,media=(string)video,framerate=30/1,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=JPEG,clock-rate=(int)90000 ! rtpstreamdepay ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegparse ! matroskamux streamable=1 ! filesink location=C:/video.mkv
It says Pipeline is PREROLLING, PREROLLED, and setting pipeline to PLAYING with New Clock.
Although it is recording albeit only the first frame, clock is stuck at 0:00:00.0/99:99:99 and so, opening the mkv file, the VLC player only shows the first frame.
I've tried many different variations, online search is challenging, tried with videoconvert, decodebin, jpegdec, mp4mux, mpegtsmux, matroskamux, queue, etc.
Thanks for the help.

You may need to add rtpjitterbuffer between rtpstreamdepay and rtpjpegdepay:
gst-launch-1.0 -e tcpclientsrc ! application/x-rtp-stream,encoding-name=JPEG ! rtpstreamdepay ! rtpjitterbuffer ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegparse ! matroskamux ! filesink location=test_mjpg.mkv

Note that rtpjitterbuffer has a latency property with default value of 2000 ms, you may later adjust for your case.
